# Why DFS transversal without the duplicates is a valid cycle?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, approximation, traveling-salesman

So I am studying apporiximation algorithms for TSP problem and there is a step that I don't get.
Essentially trying to solve TSP means we are looking for a minimum cost Hamiltonian path.
The well-known 2-approximate algorithm computes the MST , transverses it with DFS while noting down the vertices .
**I don't get how from there, we get a valid (Hamiltonian) path** .
In dfs transversal we find duplicates exactly because some vertices are not connected but do have common ancestors. By deleting the duplicates how can we 'jump' from one another?

For example here in 7.46 we get an explanation for the path from MST https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zM5MW5NKZJg

Comment: a TSP solution doesn't need to follow a hamiltonion path, it is sufficient that all nodes are visited *at least* once. Which may include more than *exactly once*

Comment: @ratchetfreak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem, in the section "as a graph problem" is mentioned "It is a minimization problem starting and finishing at a specified vertex after having visited each other vertex exactly once. " or the definition here https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture19.pdf

Comment: TSP is usually defined on complete graphs only, with the triangle inequality. And when the graph is not complete, we consider its shortest-path metric, which is equivalent to allowing vertices to be repeated.

Comment: @Guyslain No it is not usually defined on complete graphs with triangle inequality (although the 2-approximation OP is referring to requires that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2-approx algorithm you are referring to works on a special kind of TSP called the [Metric TSP](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2011/lectures/lecture_2.pdf) . In this version of TSP the graph must be complete and edge weights must satisfy the triangle inequality.

Since the graph is complete, if you delete a repeating edge after the modified DFS, you will replace it with an edge that directly connects the vertices.